# CMake: specifying build toolchain

Tags: makefile, build-automation, cmake, cross-compiling

Very new to CMake, and so far I'm finding it to be extremely helpful. I have a set of custom libraries that I would like to build for multiple platforms using cross-compilation. The toolchains are installed, and I can hand-create the `Makefile`s that I need to do so, but I would like to be able to make use of CMake.

Is there a way to tell `cmake` which toolchain to use, either at the command line or in the `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling): basically, you define a "toolchain file" that sets things like the system name, paths to compilers and so on. You then call `cmake` like so:

```
cmake /path/to/src -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain/foo-bar-baz.cmake
```

Comment: Looks like what I was looking for; will give that a try.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. this will save me a lot of headaches as I start migrating my source trees to use `cmake` instead of my hand-crafted Makefiles.

Comment: Currently I am in the process of setting up a project, which will be developed exclusively with the Emscripten SDK.

Is there a way to specify the toolchain file inside the CMakeLists.txt-file?

Comment: Where are the toolchain files that correspond to CMake's out-of-the-box options?

Comment: is there any way to configure cmake to use a specific toolchain file from the project configuration file (i.e., avoid specifying `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` every time i need to configure a build?)

Comment: CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Comment: @thang Was that in a clean build directory (e.g rm -rf build; mkdir build; cd build; cmake ...)? The error you saw could mean you need to start from scratch. If it is not from this cause perhaps you have started your own question?

Comment: @cardiffspaceman is correct. Cleaning the project fixed the issue for me. I also had to do this: `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE $ENV{CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE})`

Comment: I found that while the path-to-src can be a relative path (i.e. `..`), the `/path/to/toolchain` must be an absolute path.

Comment: using the same approach 
cmake /path/to/src -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${NDK_HOME}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
it generates a binary file, but how can i launch or run it in an andorid device or simulator ?

Answer (score 3):

To customize the build settings so you don't have to specify the parameter every time:

For Visual Studio - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=msvc-160)

For Vusual Studio Code :

Install the **Cmake Tools** extension if haven't done so already.
In the .vscode/**settings.json** file set the parameter **cmake.configureArgs**. You can also set it from **Settings** `->` **CMake Tools configuration** `->` **Add Item**. Mine looks like this:

```
{
    "cmake.configureArgs": [
        "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/.../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please explain the link for Visual Studio - how it answers the question.

Comment: here some info for VSCode cross-compiling config: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/kits.html